# What does <<< mean in the shell script?

Tags: shell

My array `arr` seems to get sorted after doing `sorted_arr=($(sort<<<${arr[@]}))`.  What does `<<<` mean here?

Answer (score 1):

The notation is a [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) in Bash and maybe some related shells ([according](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932369/what-does-mean-in-the-shell-script/28933605?noredirect=1#comment46123142_28933605) to [mkelement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), 'some related shells' includes both the Korn shell, `ksh`, and `zsh`).

However, in a larger context, the notation used with the `sort` is pointless since the value in `<<< ${arr[@]}` is a single line of data.  Since `sort` operates on lines of data and a single line of data is already in sorted order (relative to the zero other lines of data), there is no point in invoking `sort` on it.  To experiment:

```
arr=(3 2 1)
echo ${arr[@]}
sort <<< ${arr[@]}
```

The output is:

```
3 2 1
3 2 1
```

To sort the data in the array, you probably need something like:

```
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}" | sort
```

which outputs:

```
1
2
3
```

as desired.

Comment: Two other shells that support `<<<` are `ksh` and `zsh`. Since "which is therefore already sorted" could be confusing: `sort` operates on _lines_ (or parts thereof), so by definition there's nothing to sort if the entire input is a _single_ line.

Answer (score 0):

It is a so called "here string":

http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html